# How to set up Cron to run mysqlauditgrep command for 11AM on Friday

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I am trying to set up cron to run the `mysqlauditgrep` command (its the MySQL 5.6 Utilities package). The `mysqlauditgrep` command is in bash.

The command I am looking to run is:

```
mysqlauditgrep --format=GRID /var/lib/mysql/audit.log
```

This command will make my audit log that has been created by `mysql` to be viewed in a Grid format. It is not run in the `mysql` shell.

So I just installed Cron and set up the crontab by setting this:

```
00 11 * * fri root usr/bin/mysqlauditgrep   mysqlauditgrep --format=GRID /var/lib/mysql/audit.log
```

I did run `/sbin/service crond start` after I changed the crontab file.

I am unable to see if the action has taken place though.

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab entry is:

```
00 11 * * fri root usr/bin/mysqlauditgrep   mysqlauditgrep --format=GRID /var/lib/mysql/audit.log
```

The table format is:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
```

So your command seems to be:

```
usr/bin/mysqlauditgrep   mysqlauditgrep --format=GRID /var/lib/mysql/audit.log
```

Which is not valid, there is no leading `/` and the `mysqlauditgrep` is repeated.

Try this:

```
00 11 * * fri  root  /usr/bin/mysqlauditgrep --format=GRID /var/lib/mysql/audit.log
```

You can try to set a smaller interval (every minute for example) to test it without waiting a week to run.

Also check that the `mysqlauditgrep` is located in the `/usr/bin/` directory, you can locate it by the command: `which mysqlauditgrep`.

If you will get further problems, try to investigate log of your cron daemon, usually you can see all the errors there.

Comment: thanks, so i have set it for every minute, but i still doesn't seem to run. I checked the mysqlauditgrep with "which" still came up the same. I dont know if it is turned on. I was able to start up  crond, but i am having problems seeing the command being run.

I still dont know how to find the log file either

Comment: you can check whether the cron daemon is running with `ps aux | grep cron` and the logging depends on your configuration, try `cat /var/log/cron.log` or `grep cron /var/log/messages` or `grep cron /var/log/syslog`